# Read line by line from different locations please help to avoid duplicated code

Tags: bash

I've the following script.

```
for args 
do 
        while read line; do
                # do something
        done <"$args"

done
```

If the script is started with a list of filenames, it should read out each file line by line.

Now I'm looking for a way the read from stdin when script is started without a list of filenames, but I doesn't want to duplicate the while loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
[[ -z $1 ]] && defaultout=/dev/stdin

for f in "$@" $defaultout; do
  while read line; do
    # do something
  done < "$f"
done
```

Drawback: parameters are not parsed

Second attempt:

```
[[ -z $1 ]] && defaultout=/dev/stdin

for f in $@ $defaultout; do
  if [[ -f $f ]]; then
    while read line; do
      # do something
    done < "$f"
  fi
done
```

Drawback: Filenames with spaces will be parsed into two words.

Comment: What reason is the third line of the second attempt for? It's my prefered solution, but this line avoid reading from stdin.

Comment: @former I forgot to edit out that line >.< ... originally the 1st piece of code also had that line. it's a simple check to ensure that $f exists *and* is a normal file. optionally, you can change it into -e (exists, and any kind of file)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
args="$*"
if [ "$args" = "" ]; then
  args=/dev/stdin;
fi

for arg in $args; do
  while read -r line; do
    # do something
  done < "$arg";
done
```

Comment: Nice try, but not working for me. Because the "arg" includes the commandline parameters $# which where evaluated in previous while-loop and case-patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
cat "$@" | while read line; do
  # something
done
```